# SBT 0.13.6 Windows 8 - Unsolved dependencies

Tags: java, certificate

I am brand new in the world of Scala and SBT. 
I read something about SBT being a good build tool for Scala; so I went to the page and downloaded it.

I did the *Getting Started* thing and it doesn't work :-(

```
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\raoel\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

      C:\Users\raoel\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

      -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

    Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\raoel\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11
```

"raoel" is my username.

So I wen to the error log and found this in the first few lines:

```
setting 'ivy.default.settings.dir' to 'jar:file:/D:/tools/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'D:\temp\scala\.'
setting 'ivy.default.conf.dir' to 'jar:file:/D:/tools/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VsftpResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.version.PatternVersionMatcher in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.trigger.LogTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntBuildTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IvyRepResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.signer.bouncycastle.OpenPGPSignatureGenerator in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.conflict.RegexpConflictManager in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SFTPResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.updatesite.UpdateSiteResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntCallTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.MirroredURLResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.packager.PackagerResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.DualResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VfsResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.JarResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.obr.OBRResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define glob matcher: org.apache.ivy.plugins.matcher.GlobPatternMatcher was not found.
```

Do you need more? I will be happy to provide any logging that is useful.

When I look at the first warning, C:\Users\raoel.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\ exists but there's no subfolder 'jansi'.
I continue with the URL https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml and it returns a 404 in nicely formatted json.

If I look at my logfile it is looking for 'org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver' in the JAR-file located at D:/tools/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings and it is correct: SshResolver is not there.

So....  all the errors are correct. It's not working.

How do I go and fix this? It is a clean install of SBT (I did the uninstall-reinstall-thing; as a Windows-users you get quite used to it). And, why am I the only one to report this. Is it really specific to my machine? How could that be, as it is a clean install?

Do I need to configure something? JAVA_HOME is defined and correct. I wouldn't know what else it could need.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Try updating java? You have a cert issue. Are you behind a firewall or proxy? Are you able to navigate to `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom`?

Comment: I concur with @drstevens. This isn't a problem with sbt but an SSL Certificate issue with your JVM or a networking issue at your site. Try directing your browser to the locations reported by "Server access Error"

Comment: I could open the URL's mentioned in the errors, so no proxies or network-problemens.  I looked a bit more into Java and certificates and I noticted `jre\lib\security\cacerts` in my JDK-folder was only 2KB whereas this file in my SDK-folder was 91KB. Overwriting the JDK-version with the SDK-version helped!  I can remember doing something with Certificates several months back; I think I removed and recreated the file at some point. But ofcourse the Global Certificate Providers were not added.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point I emptied my `jre\lib\security\cacerts` file. It was re-created, but the Global Certificate Providers were missing.

I could've reinstalled Java, but I copied the file from another version that was still installed.